# Normalize time data between datasets in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 2 datasets I want to overlay on a single plot, but the data have been taken at different times, so my data is not overlayed, and the 2 data sets are 30 min apart. I want the 2 graphs to be on top of each other, the relative evolution through time is important, but not the absolute time at which data was taken, which is what the graphs show right now
[image]

How do I do this? Here is how my dataframes are built.

```
Time                  Raw_Touchpad0_Rx1_Tx2
2020-11-03 14:50:00   2702
2020-11-03 14:50:01   2704
```

Here is my code

```
X3500um_15_30_45_tx2rx1 <- data.frame(Time = c(2020-11-03 14:50:00, 2020-11-03 14:50:01), Raw_Touchpad0_Rx1_Tx2 = c(2702, 2704))

X15_30_45_rx2tx2 <- data.frame(Time = c(2020-11-03 15:20:00, 2020-11-03 15:20:01), Raw_Touchpad0_Rx1_Tx2 = c(2782, 27804))
 
ggplot(X3500um_15_30_45_tx2rx1, aes(as.numeric(Time), Raw_Touchpad0_Rx1_Tx2)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = Raw_Touchpad0_Rx1_Tx2)) +   
  geom_line(data = X15_30_45_rx2tx2, aes(colour = Raw_Touchpad0_Rx1_Tx2))
```

I want both plots to start at 0 time and evolve to 1 sec, 2 sec, etc instead of 14:50 vs 15:20
Thanks

Comment: I would substract the starting time of each data.frame (aka line) to get the differecne in the unit needed (min or sec...)  and plot

Comment: @DPH How would that be done exactly? I am unsure of how to operate on a whole column in a simple manner :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution to set both lines to start at 0 secs would be (example on one data.frame but applies to the second the same way):

```
# one of your test data.frames (note that I included ")
X3500um_15_30_45_tx2rx1 <- data.frame(Time = c("2020-11-03 14:50:00", "2020-11-03 14:50:01"), Raw_Touchpad0_Rx1_Tx2 = c(2702, 2704))

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# The calculation to get a new column of the difference from minimum timestamp
X3500um_15_30_45_tx2rx1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Time = lubridate::as_datetime(Time)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(DIF = Time - min(Time))
```